# Feit-Thompson's odd order theorem

Tags: reference-request

I could not find the original paper by Feit and Thompson about solvability of groups of odd order. Is there any pdf version of this paper?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After googlng I got this -

1)https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31811/feit-thompson-theorem-the-odd-order-paper

2)https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1103053943

Also there can be many other sources!

Comment: If you check your link you will notice that this not "the paper" !

Comment: Original proof about 250 pages ? Where is it ?

Comment: To me it looks like the correct link. It's just the first chapter. You have to click on "Next article" to see the next chapter and so on.

Comment: Second link allows you to download a paper in PDF format.

Comment: I had found this but i did not notice it. You are right.